Unable to create Win11 VM with OS Image under 126GB
My goal is to create a Win11 image in Azure with a OS disk size of 80GB (so it can be used as an image for AWS Workspace).
I can see that the UI in Azure does not let me create a VM with a disk size of less than 126GB.
I can also see that you cannot reduce the size of the OS disk once it's created.
Since I cannot create it on the UI, I am trying to create it using PowerShell with the following steps:
Step 1: Create Disk with WIndows as OS and 80GB as disk size:
$diskconfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $location -DiskSizeGB 80 -AccountType Standard_LRS -OsType Windows -CreateOption Empty

$disk = New-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "AIBManagedIDRG" -DiskName "win11small" -Disk $diskconfig  

Step 2: Set the VM config and the OS Disk (Giving it the DIsk ID I created in step 1)
$vm_adfs = New-AzVMConfig -VMName "win11small" -VMSize "Standard_DS1_V2"

$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm_adfs -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption FromImage -Windows

Step 3: Set the OS and add the Network Interface:
$vm = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName "win11" -Credential $vm_cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate

$vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xx-xx/resourceGroups/AIBManagedIDRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/myNic"

$vm = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $vm_adfs -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop' -Offer 'windows-11' -Skus 'win11-23h2-ent' -Version latest

Step 4: Create the VM:
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "AIBManagedIDRG" -Location "uksouth" -VM $vm  -Verbose

When I try to create the VM, I get the following error:
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Parameter 'osDisk.managedDisk.id' is not allowed.
ErrorTarget: osDisk.managedDisk.id
StatusCode: 400
Can someone please help me with this?
What am I doing wrong?
Kind Regards,
Dean

If you want to create an image, why not just spinn up hyper V and install/sysprep your image there? You have more control in Hyper v about the disk size

That is my backup plan alright but this issue is annoying me and would like to get it resolved :)

I do agree with Julian Hüppauff,You can use Hyper-V to create a VM with a disk size of 80GB and install the OS on the same disk. In Hyper-V, you have more control over the disk size.
In Azure, if you want to create a VM with  Windows OS default 126GB  and Linux default 30GB of disk space, regardless of how you are creating the VM.
You can use below PowerShell script to create VM  disk size of 80GB
$location = "eastus"
$resourceGroupName = "Venkat"
$diskconfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $location -DiskSizeGB 80 -AccountType "Standard_LRS" -OsType "Windows" -CreateOption Empty
$osDisk = New-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName "win11small" -Disk $diskconfig 
$azureVnetSubnet = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "vnet-eastus-1" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Subnets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "snet-eastus-1"}
$azureNIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "venkatNIC1" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -SubnetId $azureVnetSubnet.Id -Force

#Step 3: Set VM Credentials
$VMLocalAdminUser = "Venkat"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welcome@123$" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword)
$VMName ="win11small"   
$azureVmOsDiskName = "venkat"
$azureVmSize = "Standard_F4s_v2"
$NIC = Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name "DEMONIC"  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $azureVmSize
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $azureNIC.Id
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -StorageAccountType "Premium_LRS" -Name $VMName -CreateOption Attach -Windows -DeleteOption Delete -Verbose
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose

Output:


Thank you @Venkat V for your response. I ran your code and it was indeed able to create the VM with the OS disk but the issue is that there is no operating system when I go to the VM, then Settings and the Operating system. So I added one more line to your code: $VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop' -Offer 'windows-11' -Skus 'win11-23h2-ent' -Version latest . When I do that, I get the following error: "Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared gallery image".

Would you know how to mount an OS disk that has win11 as it's OS?

P.S. Yes I agree with you that the disk should be a lot greater than 80GB but one of the BYOL requirements for AWS Workspaces is that the OS disk size be less than 80GB - see Step 3 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/byol-windows-images.html#windows_images_create_image_byol

Hi @degan93, In Azure if you want to create VM with windows OS, you need at least 126GB disk space and for Linux default 30GB for installing required services with OS.

Hi @Venkat, so you literally cannot use PS to create a Win11 VM that has a OS disk of 80GB?
